# Change color Marker Geochart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization

I'm using [Geochart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) and I need to set different colors for the marker :

- Production Countries : red
- Raw Material Countries : blue
- ...

On the doc it's just noticed how to change the color of the axis using colorAxis.colors property, but I don't need axis on my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the second column in the data table,
in conjunction with the `colorAxis.colors` option,
to specify specific colors...

use two numbers to specify the color in the second column

in the following working snippet,
`0='red'`
`1='blue'`

note: the following option will hide the legend / axis scale...
`legend: 'none'`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawMarkersMap,
  packages: ['geochart'],
  mapsApiKey: 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
});

function drawMarkersMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Color', 'Size'],
    ['US', 0, 100],
    ['Mexico', 1, 100],
    ['Canada', 1, 100],
    ['Brazil', 0, 100]
  ]);

  var options = {
    colorAxis: {
      colors: ['red', 'blue']
    },
    displayMode: 'markers',
    legend: 'none'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

**EDIT**

to remove the color and size values from the tooltip (on hover),
add new column for custom tooltip,
either provide additional content for the tooltip,
or just a blank string (`''`) to hide color & size

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawMarkersMap,
  packages: ['geochart'],
  mapsApiKey: 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
});

function drawMarkersMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Color', 'Size', {role: 'tooltip', type: 'string', p: {html: true}}],
    ['US', 0, 100, ''],
    ['Mexico', 1, 100, ''],
    ['Canada', 1, 100, ''],
    ['Brazil', 0, 100, '']
  ]);

  var options = {
    colorAxis: {
      colors: ['red', 'blue']
    },
    displayMode: 'markers',
    legend: 'none',
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

note option for html tooltips...

```
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
    }
```

Comment: Thats help me a lot. Thank you very much

Comment: How can I hide the color and size on the hover of the circle ?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.